# firebase functions date query

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

Im trying to run a cron job to delete old notifications. Following a post on this on medium:
https://medium.com/@varunpvp/how-to-schedule-a-firebase-cloud-function-ded2db0cf9f3

This is where im up to:

```
  const oneMonthOld = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now().toMillis() - 2592000000;

  const oldNotifications = await admin.firestore()
    .collection('notifications')
    .where('createdAt', '>', oneMonthOld);
```

I've created a document in this collection. I have other queries in the function working against this collection. The article sais that more than is < (?) i've tried both ways round

```
const results2 = await oldNotifications.get();

  results2.forEach(doc => {
    console.log('in function');
    oldNotificationsBatch.delete(doc.ref);
  });
```

the function neither deletes the record or emits the log in the UI

Can anyone suggested whats going wrong here?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can compare a timestamp to milliseconds in the query. What happens if you reconstruct a timestamp our of `oneMonthOld` with https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#frommillis?

Comment: I suggest: 1) showing an example of a document that you're expecting to match from this query, 2) showing examples of queries that do work the way you expect.  There should be enough information in the question that anyone can reproduce the scenario.